# is there anyway to extract the underlineing "raw data" from a python unicode string?

Tags: python, unicode

I come to this problem with pymssql. I have a mssql db whose encoding is gbk, but it seems that pymssql can not support this. when I use 'gbk' as charset it throw an `OperationalError 20017` with some useless message, and when I try 'cp936' it just crash...

I can make successful connection with 'UTF-8' and can execute query with `sqlstr.encode('utf-8')`, the problem is that it returns unicode sting containing non-unicode content.

For example, one query return a unicode string `u'Port 26 \xb5\xe7'`, but this is wrong, it is not a unicode string and it can't decode/encode at all, it should be `'Port 26 \xb5\xe7'` (for python 2.x), thus it can be decoded with gbk and get the correct result

So my task is to extract the raw content from the unicode string. well I think I can do this from repr with some string truncate and then call eval on it, but i'm just wondering is there any more pythonic way?

Comment: If all else fails, you can encode `u'Port 26 \xb5\xe7'` to Latin-1, then decode with UTF-8: `result.encode('latin1').decode('utf8').

Comment: But perhaps it is time to switch to a different MySQL connector? Have you tried `yoursql`?

Comment: Last but not least, what is the exception you see when you try `cp936`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- `.decode('utf-8')` will raise an exception - you will have to use `gpk` or `cp936` (of course you are right about the `latin-1` part).

Comment: Yeah, I meant `gbk` there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- when i use cp936, the python interpreter crashes(python.exe has encountered a error blahblah). my db is mssql not mysql~

Comment: Ah, right, misunderstood. So then you are screwed with a buggy connection driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
>>> myString = u'Port 26 \xb5\xe7'
>>> print myString.encode('latin1').decode('gbk')
Port 26 电
```

In fact, you can use any of these as your encoding codec:

```
cp1250
cp1252
cp1254
cp1256
cp1258
latin_1
iso8859_3
iso8859_9
iso8859_15
```

latin1 is your best choice though (most inclusive).  The cp codecs listed are all Windows based.

Comment: you are right, i run some test code like: `for i in xrange(256): print i, repr(chr(i).decode('iso8859_3'))' and only latin_1 works perfect, cp1256 runs with no exception but some character is converted to unicode charactars('\uxxxx'), while other encodings end with decoding exception. thanks for your additional commit

Comment: Only latin_1 / cp1250 will have bytes in the range 0-255 mapped directly to raw bytes.